# How to print all of 1 month (and year) in multidimensional array (c#)

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I currently have a multidimensional array on which I would like to print out all rows given the criteria of a month. So if January is selected, it prints out all the data between 1930 and 2016 as long as the month is January. Any suggestions? As for the year the same principle, with the year selected and printing all values for that year.

Comment: Could you, please, provide the expected output?

Comment: ID   Year   Month   Data
1     1930 Jan        56.12
2     1931  Jan       44.12

Comment: and the same sort of thing for the year where it prints all the values for the year specified for by the user

Comment: What is the definition of your `multidimensional array`?

Comment: a side note currently the month is in full month format in a string (January, February, March etc.) I am unsure as to how to have it so that i can sort the entire array based on the order of month from ascending to descending

Comment: multiArray is the name of it.

Answer (score 0):

It's *unclear* for me what kind of *multidimensional array* you want; in any case, I suggest using *Linq*, e.g to get `IEnumerable<DateTime>` which you can (easily?) transform into structure you actually want:

```
   int month = 1; // 1 for Jan, 2 for Feb etc.

   var dates = Enumerable
     .Range(1930, 2016 - 1930 + 1)
     .SelectMany(year => Enumerable
                           .Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month))
                           .Select(day => new DateTime(year, 1, day)));

   // Let's test
   String report = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
     dates.Select(date => date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")));

   // 01-01-1930
   // 02-01-1930
   ...
   // 31-01-1930
   // 01-01-1931
   // ...
   // 31-01-2016
   Console.Write(report);
```